# Почему нет кнопок для смены месяцев на календаре ionic

Tags: angular, ionic

Использую календарь в своем проекте, но почему-то не видно кнопок для перехода между месяцами

```
 <ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
    (onChange)="onChange($event)"
    [type]="type"
    [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
  </ion-calendar>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]